# Transpose SQL row headers to first column

Tags: sql, pivot, transpose

What is the shortest, fastest, easiest way to transpose the results of the query below?  I want the 0-3 and 3-6 to show in the first column.  Sorry but this is one of those things that will boggle me for days if I don't reach out.  Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN CMAPR BETWEEN 0 AND 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [0-3],
       SUM (CASE WHEN CMAPR BETWEEN 3.01 AND 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [3-6]
FROM TBL
```

[image]

**Current Results:**

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN CMAPR >= 0 AND CMAPR <=3 THEN '0-3'
             WHEN CMAPR <= 6 THEN '3-6'
             ELSE 'Other'
        END) AS grp, COUNT(*)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN CMAPR >= 0 AND CMAPR <=3 THEN '0-3'
               WHEN CMAPR <= 6 THEN '3-6'
               ELSE 'Other'
          END);
```

The only downside is that this will not return a group if it has no rows.

You can simply unpivot your query by doing:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM (SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN CMAPR BETWEEN 0 AND 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [0-3],
             SUM (CASE WHEN CMAPR BETWEEN 3.01 AND 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [3-6]
      FROM TBL
     ) x CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES ('[0-3]', [0-3]), ('[3-6]', [3-6])) v(which, val);
```

Comment: Wow, I'm gonna have to check that one out too.